# How can I delete just 1 or 2 message

Tags: iphone

How can I delete just 1 or 2 sent or received text messages without deleting the whole text conversation?

Comment: Which version of iOs ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on the person's name from the Message screen. This will take you to a record of all the messages you have exchanged with that number.
2. Click on the edit button at the top right of the screen.
3. Choose the message or messages you would like to delete. If you change your mind and decide not to delete any, simply go to the "Done" button at the top right of the page.
4. Once you've finished selecting all of the messages you would like to delete, just tap the "Delete" button at the bottom of the page!

Comment: every since I did an update on my phone that edit button is not there instead it says contact.

Comment: @Jul which update?

Comment: not sure husband does that stuff

Comment: @Jul then see [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2188)

Answer (score 0):

Just hold down with the finger for 2. sec. on the message you want to delete, and then select "More..." - now you can select more message and when you have chosen all the message you want to delete, you click on the trash icon, and the message(s) are gone.